# How to log into separate files per thread using EclipseLink

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, eclipselink

**Scenario**: Multi-threaded application that interacts with a relational database using EclipseLink JPA Implementation

**Desired**: Having each thread to log SQL activity to a different file

The [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging) states that it's possible to use the following property to specify which file the persistence unit should log to:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="output.log"/>
```

Also, the documentation states that it's possible to include a thread identifier into the set of logged informations using the following property:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="true"/>
```

Unfortunately, the most one can get from the combination of these two properties is a unique file with logging information of all the threads in mixed order. This will likely force to post-process the file in some way (e.g. grep) to obtain a "log-per-thread".

Is there any way that I'm missing to obtain this? And if so, is it necessarily a programmatic solution?

Comment: I assume this is Java?  I'd create your own logging wrapper that uses a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: I think you're going to need to do this as a custom logger http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomLogger .  If you write your own logger you can retrieve the thread id (`Thread.getCurrentThread().getId()`) / thread name and choose where to write each SessionLogEntry to based on that.

Comment: Yes it is Java, and you just gave me enough hints to come to a solution. Thank you, I'll post a possible solution as an answer as soon as possible